# Getting a JDBC connection from EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, jdbc, connection, eclipselink

using EclipseLink as JPA 2.0 provider, I can obtain a JDBC connection by simply calling

```
Connection con = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
```

But I'm unsure what I'm responsible for. Do I have to close the connection after submitting my queries? Or are I'm not allowed to close the connection, because EclipseLink also uses this connection internally. Or does it not care, because EclipseLink observes my behaviour and closes the connection automatically if I don't do it?

Comment: Why do you need a connection? JPA uses EntityManager in most of the situations.

Comment: To call stored procedures. Calling them via EclipseLink is not supported by my DBMS.

Comment: What DBMS are you on that EclipseLink cannot handle the stored procedures for you?

Answer (score 10):

If you are in the context of a JPA transaction the connection will be managed by the provider (EclipseLink).  If you are outside of a transaction you are responsible for managing the connection yourself.

See the following link for additional information:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager

Comment: I have a problem. Transaction always commits changes, even if I will do a rollback on the entity manager. I'm using Informix db and ifxjdbc driver. Transaction is application managed.
And second problem is that eclipselink returns null on unwrap(java.sql.Connection). Using eclipselink 2.5.1 with old SGES2.1.1.

Comment: Resolved: The EclipseLink wiki was wrong but it's unwrap method is correct. I have fixed Eclipselink's wiki today.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but as of Jul2019, using eclipselink 2.5.0 and querydsl 4.2.1, the proposed unwrap(Connection.class) approach returns null in my own project. Solved it by creating the needed JPASQLQuery and passing the existing entityManager as parameter (see http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/sql/JPASQLQuery.html)

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm unsure what I'm responsible for. Do I have to close the
>   connection after submitting my queries? Or are I'm not allowed to
>   close the connection, because EclipseLink also uses this connection
>   internally.

A good and valid question. It seems that the documentation is lacking the semantics of the `unwrap()` calls.

**Regarding EclipseLink**, according from what I got from the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.4.2/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EntityManagerImpl.java#2533):

EclipseLink gives you a **reference** to the currently active `connection` which it uses for the currently **active client session transaction**. If no transaction is active, a **new will be created**, associated with the session and returned from the `unwrap()` method.

As a result, IMHO, a commit/rollback of such a obtained `Connection` may lead to undefined behavior and/or exceptions. Same is true for executing DML which changed records have been previously cached by eclipselink internal caches or for which managed entities exist.
So when using this API, especially if the underlying transaction is dirty, **be careful**.

If you can refer to internal eclipselink classes, you can access eclipselink internal connection pool to get a `Connection` exclusively (have a look at `org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.getConnectionPool(String)` ).