# Getting sql connection via EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I am trying to obtain a reference to sql connection as mentioned in the following question :

[Getting a JDBC connection from EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710700/getting-a-jdbc-connection-from-eclipselink)

Here is the actual code: 
    Connection con = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
This is also mentioned in EclipseLink documentation.

I keep getting following error from EclipseIDE:

```
The method unwrap(Class<Connection>) is undefined for the type EntityManager

1 Quickfix Add cast to 'entityManager'
```

If I apply the quickfix suggested by Eclipse, the code looks like this:

```
Connection con = ((java.sql.Wrapper) entityManager).unwrap(Connection.class);
```

Now, the code compiles and I can deploy my application but as soon the method is called, following error occurs:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy427 cannot be cast to java.sql.Wrapper
```

How can I solve this problem. I have an entityManager instance and using it, I want to get the dbname, db url and db schema verion

Comment: Which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.6

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046491/jpa-is-there-a-way-method-to-retrieve-persistence-unit-information

Comment: I have deleted it Sir, thank you very much for your time . And if you  care to spend a little more time, you would know that the suggested solutions didn,t work and thats why I am asking again!

Comment: which jpa version are using?

Comment: JPA version 2.0

Comment: As I told you on the previous post https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29   that method exists. If your compiler says no then you are NOT using JPA 2.0