# Getting Database url, name and schema version via native query

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink with Oralce DB and would like to get database name, schema version and url via EntityManager. I have already tried solution mentioned in following question

[Getting a JDBC connection from EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710700/getting-a-jdbc-connection-from-eclipselink)

But this approach is not working for me and I have mentioned the problem in following question:

[Getting sql connection via EclipseLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549872/getting-sql-connection-via-eclipselink)

I would like to know how can I get the required data directly via native query. I have an instance of entityManager and using it, I can execute native queries and get what I want

Comment: What is a "schema version?"  Which url?   The one you connected with?

Comment: For what purposes? EclipseLink logs this information when it logs in to the database at the right log level. Otherwise, unless you are going to unwrap the connection as you are having problems with in your other questions, you are looking at a more Oracle SQL type answer, not EclipseLink or JPA.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298005/how-to-find-schema-name-in-oracle-when-you-are-connected-in-sql-session-using for instance